# Is there any C implementation of in process persistent queue which I can readily use

Tags: c, queue, persistent-storage

I'm looking for any persistent queue implementation which I can use within my c process. Would prefer something which offers crash consistancy as well.I have considered RabbitMQ, beanstalk etc. But these are more extensive and allows message passing between diffrent processes and even diffrent nodes. These would be too much overhead. Threads within the same process will be the producers and consumers in my use case.